# [FFmpeg]Randomly adding beep sound to video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to add beep sounds at the arbitrary position to the videos. My purpose is to make the video soundtrack unusable, but can still know its contents and the audio quality.
My first thought is creating a beep soundtrack has the same length as the video and combine them. Are there any better ways to achieve my purpose? I've found some answers on this site but they're pretty old.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Seems like it would be annoying to listen to.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Some copyright issues.